# Finding the upper and lower bounds, positive and negative each if applicable, for a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $|z^4 -8 + 3|, |z|=2 $

I need to find the positive upper and lower bounds of the above expression.

My attempt:

By triangle inequality, we have

$||z^4|+|-8z|+3|\geq|z^{4} -8z + 3| \leq  ||z^4 -8z| +3|???||z^4|+|3-8z|| \geq ||z^4|-|8z|+3|\geq||z^4+3|-|8z|| $

(I used ??? since I don't know which is larger than which, and I believe i got all the combinations possible)

At the left most, I believe that will give me the upper bound so $|2^4|+|-8(2)|+3| = 35$

At the right most, $||2^4 +3| -|8(2)| = 3|$

BUT, and here is my question, given that $z = r*e^{i\theta}, |e^{i\theta}| = 1$

assuming my triangle inequality is true, we know $|8z| = |8r*e^{i\theta}|=|8r|$, however $|z^4+3|$ is not necessarily equal to $|r^4 +3|$, I wonder if $|z^4+3| = |8z|$ such that $||z^4+3|-|8z||= 0$ ?

Alternatively if $|z^4 - 8z| = -3$ is possible??

Comment: Maximizing the expression is easy: you want $(4\theta), (-\theta),$ and $(0)$ to all point in the same direction.  $(\theta = \pi)$ works, and is easily seen to result in the maximum, by the triangle inequality theorem.  Minimizing the expression seems like no walk in the park, and I (for one) am out of my depth.  One approach is to resort to $z = x + iy$, compute $f(z)$, then compute $g(z) = |f(z)|$, and then compute $g'(z)$ (a multivariable derivative) in terms of $x,y$.  Then, when trying to factor $g'(z) = 0$, you will be aided by knowing that one of the factors must be where $(y=0)$.

Comment: A totally different approach would be to examine the 4 complex roots $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4$ of $(z^4 - 8z + 3) = 0$, which as a quartic, must be solvable.  Then, one might surmise that you identify the 4 points $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$ on the circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin that are the *closest* to $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4$, and then choose $\min[|f(z_1)|, |f(z_2)|, |f(z_3)|, |f(z_4)|]$.  One of the difficulties here is that I don't know enough about Complex Analysis to assert that this will minimize $|f(z)|$.

Comment: arh! great idea. I just tried inputting $(z^4 -8z +3 =0)$ into wolfram alpha, it seems none of the roots lie on a circle of radius 2.

So....i guess that means that for |z| = 2, $(z^4 -8z +3 =0)$ has no solution?

Comment: Re-read my 2nd comment.  You have to identify $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4$, then identify $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4.$  However, the problem is obviously looking for rigor.  The approach in the 2nd comment does you no good, even if it leads to minimizing $|f(z)|$ unless you can **prove** that you have minimized $|f(z)|$.

Comment: Yet a 3rd approach is to examine the roots of $(z^4 - 8z + 3 = k)$, and choose $k$ so that $|k|$ is minimized and one of the 4 roots is on the circle of radius $2$.  Again, you would have to prove that the $k$ that you have chosen leads to the minimum value for $|k|$.

Comment: Oh, I actually (via WA) got 4 roots $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$, I just manually find the corresponding r values of each(from the approximate values returned by WA) and none of them(r values) = 2(close to 2 but not 2, so I am abit worried). Does this count?

well, regarding proving of minimisation, I was thinking if my list of triangle inequalities are correct, if so, then i believe I can just use the one that seems to be the smallest.

I was just worried, that because of complex numbers, I could end up with some paradox that counters my triangle inequality logic above.

Comment: I emphasize that the point of the problem is not to minimize $|f(z)|$ but to prove that you have minimized $|f(z)|$.  Is this problem from a book/class that you are in?  If so, there should have been some previous theorems, solved problems, or worked examples that led up to this problem that you can regard as both **training** and **tools**.  Rather than try to solve the problem in a vacuum, why not identify your tools, and then try to use them?

Comment: Arh, i shouldn't be making excuses, but our course notes and our lecture notes have slightly different content because the respective person IC are different.

For my lecture/class, the only things I can think of that are helpful are triangle inequality and squeeze theorem, will try looking at course notes.
thank you!

Comment: $|\text{anything}|=-3$ is not a possibility.

Comment: Is your first line intended to read $\cdots |z^4 -8z + 3| \cdots?$

Comment: Given the expression $f(z)=|z^4-8z+3|$ and the constraint that $z$ lies on a circle centered at the origin with radius $2$, $(|z|=2)$, we seek upper and lower bounds of $f(z)$. $\cdots$

Comment: @mjw, yes the 1st line is $|z^4 -8z +3|$

Answer (score 2):

Given two complex numbers $a$ and $b$, then the triangle inequality is $$||a|-|b|| \le |a -b| \le |a|+|b|$$

Hence, if we want simple bounds, assuming $|z|=2$, then we can do the following, $$13= |16-3| = ||-8z|-|3|| \le |-8z+3| \le |-8z|+|3| = 16+3 = 19$$ Hence, $|-8z+3|$ is bounded between $13$ and $19$ (notice that it could be $16$). Thus, we have $$0\le |16-|-8z+3||=||z^4|-|-8z+3||\le |z^4-8z+3| \le |z^4|+|8z|+3 = 35$$ So, you have lower bound $0$ and upper bound $35$.

---

If you want tighter bounds, you could solve the absolute value explicitly. That is, let $z=x+yi$, then assuming $|z|=2$ we have that $y^2 = 4 - x^2$, so we perform substitution, $$|(x+yi)^4-8(x+yi)+3| $$ $$= |(x^4-6x^2y^2+y^4-8x+3)+(4x^3y-4xy^3-8y)i|$$ $$=\sqrt{(x^4-6x^2y^2+y^4-8x+3)^2+(4x^3y-4xy^3-8y)^2}=\sqrt{48x^4-256x^3-192x^2+720x+617}$$ we can explicitly take the derivative of the polynomial ($192x^3-768x^2-384x+720$) in the square root and find the absolute maximum and absolute minimum, where $x$ is between $-2$ and $2$. Doing so we find the absolute minimum is $1.79964$ and is found with $x=-1.0785$ ($z=-1.0785+1.68429i$), likewise the absolute maximum is $35$ and is found with $x=-2$ ($z=-2+0i$). So we have exact bounds, $$1.79964 \le |z^4-8z+3| \le 35$$ moreover equality is achieved at specific $z=-1.0785+1.68429i$ and $z=-2$.

Comment: What I regard as very interesting is that a reasonable (but **wrong**) guess is that to minimize $|f(z)|$, you want $(4\theta)$ and $(-\theta)$ to point in opposite directions.  This leads to $(\theta = 0), (z=2),$ and $|f(z)| = 3$, which is **inferior** to your answer.

Comment: Ya, sometimes explicit the way to go. Oops, I had the wrong polynomial in the square root. :-)

Comment: I think it should be $|z^4| +|-8z+3| $ instead of $|z^4| -|-8z+3| $.

But i think the answer will be the same if I use $|z^4 + 3 - |8z||$

Also, for triangle inequality, I noted that you try to find the upper and lower bounds by parts(like my question has 3 terms, and you solve for 2, and then consider the 3rd one from the results of the previous), so I guess, that is how I should approach triangle inequalities for polynomial (more than 2 terms)?

Answer (score 0):

A point on the circle is characterized by $z=2e^{i\theta}$.

Let $g(z)=z^4 - 8z+3.$

We seek the minimum and maximum of

$\begin{aligned} |g(\theta)|^2 &= g(2e^{i\theta})\overline{ g(2e^{i\theta})}=g(2e^{i\theta})g(2e^{-i\theta})\\&=(16e^{4i\theta}-16e^{i\theta}+3)(16e^{-4i\theta}-16e^{-i\theta}+3)\end{aligned}$

Differentiatate with respect to $\theta$ to find extrema $\cdots.$